# Sharing the content of a Modal to social media

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a form and once the user inputs and clicks "submit", it loads the collected data onto a modal and shows it on screen with all the data there.

I'm trying to figure out how to share the content of the modal to social media, instead of sharing the page URL, if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I've tried adding social media share buttons into the footer of the Modal, but it still requires a URL to share from, of which the modal doesn't have:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>The results are in!</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> 
      <div class="social-links">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="{PAGEURL}"&t={PAGETITLE}" target="myModal" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      </div>
```

The form the user inputs into:

```
<fieldset>            
  <label>How old are you?</label>
  <input type="number" id="myAge" value="" min="1" max="99">
  <label >How many...</label> 
  <select id="what" name='what' onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="Cans of Coke">Cans of Coke have I drank</option>
  </select>
  <label>How many per week?</label>
  <input type="number" id="perWeek" value=""><br><br>
  <input type='submit' id='submit' value='How Many!' onclick="myFunction(), buttonHide()"/></p>
</fieldset>
```

The function to calculate the totals and push them to the Modal:

```
function myFunction(){

  var x = document.getElementById("myAge"); 
  var y = document.getElementById("perWeek");
  var z = document.getElementById("what");
  var perYear = y.value * 52;
  var perLife = perYear * x.value - 10;
  var defaultVal = z.defaultValue;
  var currentVal = z.value;
  var perLitre = perLife * 0.33;
  var perSugarC = perLife * 0.039;

  case z.value == "Cans of Coke":
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have had 
  approximately: " + perLife + " " + currentVal +  "Equaling to "+ 
  perLitre.toFixed(2) + " Litres and " + perSugarC.toFixed(2) + " kg 
  of Sugar!";
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="block";

  break;
```

The modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>The results are in!</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> 
      <div class="social-links">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="{PAGEURL}"&t={PAGETITLE}" target="myModal" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      </div>
```

The modal script:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none", window.location.reload();
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none", window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

I've also tried using the share button from the facebook dev site:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

```
function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Then adding the button into the modal footer as previously but again, requires a URL that the modal doesn't have:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```